# Container accessible with docker run and compose-up, but not with stack deploy

Tags: angular, express, docker

(Apologies if I mix any terms up, still new to Docker)

I have a dockerized Angular 5 application that has server-side rendering enabled, and is served by an Express server on port 4200 when started. I can access it on `localhost:4200` when I launch it with either `docker run -p 4200:4200 artemzakharov/tryout` or run `docker-compose up --build` in the directory with the `docker-compose.yml` file, but when I try to launch it on a swarm as done in step 3 of the Docker [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/), I can no longer figure out where it's being hosted, let alone connect to it. Putting just `localhost` in the URL bar for Chrome works for the tutorial application, but not mine, and I can't figure out what I'm doing that's different. If I run `docker service ps <name>`, I can see all of the services launched and running.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: artemzakharov/tryout
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 1024M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

[How the application looks when broken, vs loaded properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/redxr.jpg)

**Update:** I've found that I can't seem to connect when it's running in detached mode either. Seems like it's probably part of this issue.

Comment: Is your image public? I guess it is able to fetch the image, else it shouldn't deploy. Probably something fishy on express server config.

Comment: It is. Are there any express settings that would interfere with Docker? I can edit in my whole server file if that would help.

Comment: Maybe you have a `docker-compose.override.yml` which is automatically loaded if you use `docker-compose`, but not if you use `docker stack`